# Fast distance calculation in R

Tags: r, matrix, numerical-methods, euclidean-distance, mahalanobis

I'm trying to calculate the

1) Euclidean distance, and

2) Mahalanobis distance

for a set of matricies in r. I've been doing it as such:

```
v1 <- structure(c(0.508, 0.454, 0, 2.156, 0.468, 0.488, 0.682, 1, 1.832, 
            0.44, 0.928, 0.358, 1, 1.624, 0.484, 0.516, 0.378, 1, 1.512, 
            0.514, 0.492, 0.344, 0, 1.424, 0.508, 0.56, 0.36, 1, 1.384, 0.776, 
            1.888, 0.388, 0, 1.464, 0.952, 0.252, 0.498, 1, 1.484, 0.594, 
            0.256, 0.54, 2, 2.144, 0.402, 0.656, 2.202, 1, 1.696, 0.252), 
          .Dim = c(5L, 10L), 
          .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("KW_1", "KW_2", "KW_3", "KW_4", "KW_5", "KW_6", "KW_7", "KW_8", "KW_9", "KW_10")))

v2 <- structure(c(1.864, 1.864, 1.864, 1.864, 1.864, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 
            1.6, 1.6, 1.536, 1.536, 1.536, 1.536, 1.536, 1.384, 1.384, 1.384, 
            1.384, 1.384, 6.368, 6.368, 6.368, 6.368, 6.368, 2.792, 2.792, 
            2.792, 2.792, 2.792, 2.352, 2.352, 2.352, 2.352, 2.352, 2.624, 
            2.624, 2.624, 2.624, 2.624, 1.256, 1.256, 1.256, 1.256, 1.256, 
            1.224, 1.224, 1.224, 1.224, 1.224), 
          .Dim = c(5L, 10L), 
          .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("KW_1", "KW_2", "KW_3", "KW_4", "KW_5", "KW_6", "KW_7", "KW_8", "KW_9", "KW_10")))

L2 <- sqrt(rowSums((v1-v2)^2))  # Euclidean distance for each row
```

which provides:

```
[1] 7.132452 7.568359 7.536904 5.448696 7.163580
```

That's perfect! But I've heard you can also compute Euclidean/L2 distance using the following form:

[image]

I'd like to calculate my distance this way because the Mahalanobis distance is simply this and the covariance matrix. [See this](http://mccormickml.com/2014/07/22/mahalanobis-distance/#the-mahalanobis-distance).

I haven't figured out how to code this in r, however. I've tried:

```
sqrt(crossprod((t(v1)-t(v2))))
```

and

```
sqrt((v1-v2) %*% t(v1-v2))
```

But they just don't give me what I want. Suggestions?

Note - 
I'm looking to do this as a single operation, not in a loop of any kind. It has to be very fast because I'm doing it over millions of rows multiple times. Maybe it's not possible. I'm open to changing the format of `v1` and `v2`.

Comment: q <- v1 - v2; s = sum(q*q); print(sqrt(s))

Comment: Nope, I need a distance for each row. Results must match `[1] 7.132452 7.568359 7.536904 5.448696 7.163580`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the formula to each row individually, so something like:

```
> sapply(1:nrow(v1), function(i) {
+     q = v1[i, ] - v2[i, ]
+     d = sqrt(t(q) %*% q)
+     d
+ })
[1] 7.132452 7.568359 7.536904 5.448696 7.163580
```

If you need something faster you can always try the same thing in C++ (code adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36829760/1222578)):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

double dist2(NumericVector x, NumericVector y){
    double d = sqrt( sum( pow(x - y, 2) ) );
    return d;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector calc_l2 (NumericMatrix x, NumericMatrix y){
    int out_length = x.nrow();
    NumericVector out(out_length);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < out_length; i++){
        NumericVector v1 = x.row(i);
        NumericVector v2 = y.row(i);
        double d = dist2(v1, v2);
        out(i) = d;
    }
    return (out) ;
}
```

Running in R:

```
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp("calc_L2.cpp")
calc_l2(v1, v2)
```

Comment: I have millions of rows in my dataset so this won't be fast enough.

Comment: If you have constraints and requirements it would probably be a good idea to tell us about them in your question.

Comment: Dan, look up the data.table package. This will help you when dealing with such a large dataset. You will find a lot of information on using the package on this site.

Comment: @Dan: you can apply basically the same code in C++ for a speedup.

Comment: Very cool with the `Rcpp` action. I've implemented to see if I get a speed-up with L1 and unfortunately  the R vectorization of `sqrt(rowSums((v1-v2)^2))` is faster than the `for` loop in C++. That leaves two points: 1) Is there a way to translate `sqrt(rowSums((v1-v2)^2))` to C++? so as to avoid the `for` loop? and 2) How will I implement the `Mahalanobis` distance using `C++`? I'll post my best shot at this in `C++` above.

Comment: OK I couldn't figure out how to implement it so as just to take args v1 and v2

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, but R was actually faster. Still haven't done Mahalanobis though. That will necessarily be in RCPP