# How to speed up a Rcpp double for loop

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, rcpp

Since I am not an expert in C++ (or Rcpp) I was wondering if there are other / better ways to write this little function below, which uses 2 for loops to fill up a matrix based on the values of 2 other matrices.

Here is some example data:

```
  library(Rcpp)

  sizem <- 50000
  n <- 500
  k <- 5
  d <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = k, 0)
  x <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = sizem, runif(sizem*n, 0, 500))
  rownames(x) <- paste0("p-",1:n)
  v <- matrix(nrow = k, ncol = sizem, sample(0:300, size = sizem*k, T))
```

and the function currently looks like this:

```
  cppFunction("
  NumericMatrix compdistc(NumericMatrix d, NumericMatrix x, NumericMatrix v, int k, int n) {
    NumericMatrix out = clone(d);
    int i,j;
    for (j=0; j < k; ++j) {
      for (i=0; i < n; ++i) {
        out(i,j) = sum(pow((x(i,_) - v(j,_)), 2));
      }
    }
    return(out);
  }
  ")

  out <- compdistc(d, x, v, k, n)
```

and this is my current benchmark:

```
  mc <- microbenchmark(times = 10,
    out = compdistc(d, x, v, k, n)
  ); mc
```

> ```
> Unit: seconds
>  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
>   out 2.123477 2.135013 2.174556 2.148467 2.204108 2.354089    10
> ```

Comment: If you want to compute euclidean distances, try to use linear algebra instead of loop.
Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56072073/6103040.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful and good to know, although it was merely an example. It was more of a general question of how to rewrite for loops in different / better ways.

Comment: Improving code should be tailored to the code itself, unfortunately.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, it's just a lot of calculations.  I think you won't be able to improve the performance without looking into more advanced linear algebra approaches.  The fact is, you're doing 1.25e8 power calculations.  Some packages to check out: `tensorflow`, `RcppArmadillo`.

Comment: (1) There is no need to initialize `d` in R, and then clone it in cpp. You can instead initialize NumericMatrix out(n,k). (2) x, v are constant, so you can write const NumericMatrix x in your argument. That said, it won't make a noticeable difference in speed.

Comment: @inferator - What is the improvement in writing `const NumericMatrix x` instead of `NumericMatrix x`? And I also saw sometimes a `&` at the end? What is that actually for?

Comment: If you don't manipulate a matrix, and it's 'read only' in your code, you can declare it a constant. It's just proper coding. `&` is for pointers, so when you just point to data already in memory, instead of creating another copy of said data.