# Ways to improve method for calculating sets of distances in big data?

Tags: r, merge, data.table, bigdata, distance

I posted a while back about how efficiently to [calculate sets of distances using big data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70396206/big-data-ways-to-calculate-sets-of-distances-in-r). The answers there didn't quite answer my question, since the issue is more computational (e.g. like how to find k-nearest neighbors without doing a huge merge in order to calculate the distance of every point from one another) rather than an issue about calculating the distances themselves.

We've come up with a solution using a non-equi join in `data.table`, but I'd really appreciate any feedback on whether this is the right way to go/ways to improve the speed, and so on.

**A quick overview of the problem**

(See the linked post above for more detail.) We have a (in reality very large) dataset with the location of stores, for example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
ex <- data.table(x = c(5,6,7),
                 y = c(1,2,3))
```

We want to know how many other stores are within some arbitrary radius of each store. The simple, but computationally infeasible, way of doing this is basically to merge the dataset with itself and calculate the distance for every combination of stores. Obviously when you have millions of stores, though, this method would produce a huge intermediary dataset, among other issues.

**Proposed solution**

Ok now for the part I'd like feedback on. The basic idea is, in essence, to draw a square around each store, use a non-equi join to find all other stores within that "square" of the store, then calculate distances and keep only the stores within the right radius of the main store (ie. draw a circle within the initial square).

To do this, first we duplicate the store dataset and calculate variables that will hold the dimensions of the square:

```
# make copy of original dataframe with new names 
ex.c <- rename(.data = ex, xc = x, yc = y)

# make bounding box for each point in original dataframe
ex$min.x <- ex$x - 2
ex$max.x <- ex$x + 2
ex$min.y <- ex$y - 2
ex$max.y <- ex$y + 2
```

Then we merge the dataset of stores with itself, requiring the coordinates of the other stores to be within an arbitrary amount, here 2 units, of the primary store:

```
ex5 <- ex[ex.c,
          .(x.x, x.min.x, x.max.x, x.min.y, x.min.y, i.xc, i.yc),
          on = .(max.x >= xc, min.x <= xc, 
                 max.y >= yc, min.y <= yc),
          allow.cartesian = T]
ex5
   x.x x.min.x x.max.x x.min.y x.max.y i.xc i.yc
1:   5       3       7      -1       3    5    1
2:   6       4       8       0       4    5    1
3:   7       5       9       1       5    5    1
4:   5       3       7      -1       3    6    2
5:   6       4       8       0       4    6    2
6:   7       5       9       1       5    6    2
7:   5       3       7      -1       3    7    3
8:   6       4       8       0       4    7    3
9:   7       5       9       1       5    7    3
```

Then we calculate distances and from there we can keep the stores that are within the desired radius:

```
## that does the square. now we need to cut to the circle
ex5[,
    dist := sqrt((x.x - i.xc)^2 + (x.x - i.yc)^2)]

ex5
   x.x x.min.x x.max.x x.min.y x.max.y i.xc i.yc     dist
1:   5       3       7      -1       3    5    1 4.000000
2:   6       4       8       0       4    5    1 5.099020
3:   7       5       9       1       5    5    1 6.324555
4:   5       3       7      -1       3    6    2 3.162278
5:   6       4       8       0       4    6    2 4.000000
6:   7       5       9       1       5    6    2 5.099020
7:   5       3       7      -1       3    7    3 2.828427
8:   6       4       8       0       4    7    3 3.162278
9:   7       5       9       1       5    7    3 4.000000
```

I'd really appreciate any suggestions on how to improve this. The real data is quite large, so any speed improvements are especially welcome.

Comment: Where does rename function comes from? Do you use extra package for it or you just forget to include it in your repex?

Comment: It's from `dplyr`, sorry

Comment: It seem quite unreasonable to ask people to install tidyverse (or even dplyr) to run your repex, considering that you only need to rename columns. Both base R and data.table have good routines for that. Installing those heavy packages takes at least couple minutes, and all that just to rename...

Comment: You should describe more clearly with words what your problem is.  Are x and y longitude and latitude? What is desired radius? Is it same for all stores? Why is x.x used twice in distance calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants *to know how many other stores are within some arbitrary radius of each store*.

The code below elaborates OP's idea of a *non-equi self-join* but combined with *grouping by each i*. It appends a new column to `ex` which contains the requested number of other stores within a given radius.

```
library(data.table)
# sample data with an additional data point to make the use case less uniform
ex <- data.table(x = c(5, 6, 7, 5.5),
                 y = c(1, 2, 3, 1.5))
ex
```

> ```
>      x   y
> 1: 5.0 1.0
> 2: 6.0 2.0
> 3: 7.0 3.0
> 4: 5.5 1.5
> ```

```
radius <- 2 # parameter
bb_cols <- c("x.min", "x.max", "y.min", "y.max")
ex[,  (bb_cols) := .(x - radius, x + radius, y - radius, y + radius)][
  , count := .SD[.SD, on = .(x >= x.min, x <= x.max, y >= y.min, y <= y.max), 
                sum((x.x - i.x)^2 + (x.y - i.y)^2 <= radius^2) - 1L, 
                by = .EACHI]$V1][
                  , (bb_cols) := NULL]
ex
```

> ```
>      x   y count
> 1: 5.0 1.0     2
> 2: 6.0 2.0     3
> 3: 7.0 3.0     1
> 4: 5.5 1.5     2
> ```

#### Edit: Without chaining

In response to OP's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71382552/ways-to-improve-method-for-calculating-sets-of-distances-in-big-data/71443364?noredirect=1#comment126497592_71443364), the code can be written without *chaining*:

```
ex[,  (bb_cols) := .(x - radius, x + radius, y - radius, y + radius)]
ex[, count := .SD[.SD, on = .(x >= x.min, x <= x.max, y >= y.min, y <= y.max), 
                  sum((x.x - i.x)^2 + (x.y - i.y)^2 <= radius^2) - 1L, 
                  by = .EACHI]$V1]
ex[, (bb_cols) := NULL]
```

All three operations *update by reference* so no effect on performance is expected.

#### Verification

In order to verify the correctness we can plot the locations and the circles:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
ggplot(ex) + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y, colour = factor(seq_along(x)))) +
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = x, y0 = y, r = radius, colour = factor(seq_along(x)))) + 
  coord_fixed() + 
  ggtitle(sprintf("Store locations and circles of radius %.1f", radius)) +
  guides(colour = "none")
```

[image]

So, the store at location (6, 2) has 3 other other stores within a radius of 2 (green circle).

Of course, the number of adjacent stores depends on the given `radius`. With a smaller radius, the code finds less stores:

With

```
radius <- 1
```

we get

```
ex
```

> ```
>      x   y count
> 1: 5.0 1.0     1
> 2: 6.0 2.0     1
> 3: 7.0 3.0     0
> 4: 5.5 1.5     2
> ```

and accordingly

[image]

So, the store at location (7, 3) has no other stores within a radius of 1 (blue circle).

#### Explanation

The code is quite concise and uses data.table *chaining*.

1. `bb_cols <- c("x.min", "x.max", "y.min", "y.max")` are the names of the helper columns which will hold the coordinates of the bounding boxes required for the *non-equi self-join*.
2. `ex[,  (bb_cols) := .(x - radius, x + radius, y - radius, y + radius)]` creates the helper columns *by reference*, i.e., without copying the whole data.table. Please, note that *no* copy of the original dataset is required.
3. `.SD[.SD, on = .(x >= x.min, x <= x.max, y >= y.min, y <= y.max), sum((x.x - i.x)^2 + (x.y - i.y)^2 <= radius^2) - 1L, by = .EACHI]` is the key part. It implements *aggregation in a non-equi self-join*.
   The join picks all locations within the bounding box. `by = .EACHI` aggregates over all picked locations for each bounding box.
   `sum((x.x - i.x)^2 + (x.y - i.y)^2 <= radius^2)` counts how many of the locations within the bounding box are located within the circle. Note that the actual distance is not required for the comparison so we can avoid the computationally expensive `sqrt()`.
   The store at the centre of the bounding box is included in the count. This is corrected by subtracting one to count only the *other* stores within the circle.
4. The column with the counts has been named `V1` by default. It is picked from the join result and appended to `ex` as column `count` *by reference*.
5. Finally, the helper columns are removed *by reference*.

Comment: Thanks for this. A quick question if you don't mind: I usually avoid chaining just for the sake of clarity. It's my understanding that choosing to chain or not doesn't affect speed, but I could be wrong -- did you chain here just to make the code more succinct or are there computational implications?